# How to use refetch method to send different queries using useQuery in react-query

Tags: react-query

I'm working with `react-query` in ReactJS to build a website.
I have the following code, where I fetch some data using `useQuery()`:

```
    const { error, data: movie, status, refetch } = useQuery({
        queryKey: 'key1',
        queryFn: async () => {
            return await Promise.all([
                axios.get(`API-1.com/get-some-data`), /*getting some data from api-1 */
                axios.get(`API-2.com/get-some-data`), /*getting some data from api-2 */
            ]).then(([api1, ap2]) => {
                return { data1: api1, data2: api2 }
            })
        }
    })
```

The problem I'm facing is getting somtimes a 404 response from one of the apis, so I need to refetch the data just from the other api that doesn't cause the error.

I tried to use the `refetch` method inside `onError`, but it can't be used with parameters.

```
        onError: (error) => {
            refetch() /* refetch can't be used with parameters */
        },
```

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Writing the fetching part in an external function (so I can call the function with parameters)
2. Adding a try-catch block inside the `queryFn` to handle the errors

```
/********* this is the function where I fetch the data.   *********/. 
/********* with a param that tells me if i'll call API-2 or not *********/

    const fetchData = async ({ isDataFoundInApi2 }) => {
        return await Promise.all([
            axios.get(`API-1.com/get-some-data`),
            (!isDataFoundInApi2 && axios.get(`API-2.com/get-some-data`)),
        ]).then(([api1, api2]) => {
            return { data1: api1, data2: api2 }
        })

/********* the useQuery where the above method is called  *********/
/********* first it sends true as a bool value, then if no *********/
/********* data was found in API-2, it sends false       *********/
/********* from `catch` to prevent the fetching from API-2 *********/

    const { error, data: movie, status } = useQuery({
        queryKey: 'key1',
        queryFn: async () => {
            try {
                return await fetchData({}) 
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response?.status === 404)
                    return await fetchData({ isDataFoundInApi2: true }) // true means call only the first api
            }
        },
    })
```